# Stopping a Ajax Loop JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, infinite-loop

I use a ajax code to monitor a folder to count the number of files in that folder that are being copied with a external batch that I didn't have access. I have the following infinite loop that is working quite fine:

```
function loadProgWav(files){
        $("#wav").load("progress_wav.php?file=<?=$row[2]?>");
    }

    setInterval(function(){ loadProgWav(files) }, 10000);
```

The ajax return to me a formatted string with a message of how many files have in that folder. But now I need to be able to stop that loop if the **progress_wav.php** returns  ***false***, and show a submit button to redirect to another page of code, but have no idea on how do so.

I'm running the program in a Windows Server 2003 machine with Xaamp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To stop it, first create it like this:

`var interval = setInterval(function(){ loadProgWav(files) }, 10000);`

Later, when you want to stop it, simply do:

`clearInterval(interval);`

This method also applies to `setTimeout`, just use `clearTimeout` the same way.